# Easy to see that the matrix is singular

Tags: matrices, determinant

I'm studying math as a hobby on my own free time. So if the question seems too simple, I'd like to apologize.

I'm given the following matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
46 & 5 & 58 \\
4 & 0 & 5 \\
6 & 5 & 8 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The task is to find the determinant.

The solution states that it easily can be seen that this matrix is singular and therefore the determinant is equal to $0$. Unfortunately I can't see without explicitly calculating the determinant that it is singular. How did the author of this question make this determination? How can one see from this matrix that it is singular?

Comment: Hint: subtract the last row from the first, then look closely.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks. I can see it now.

Comment: We get much, much more simple questions than that, don't worry!

Comment: @dxiv I think I rushed with my answer. Shouldn't rows/columns be multiples of each other in order to be linearly dependent? I understand that if I subtract row 3 from row 1, row 1 will become a multiple of row 2. But shouldn't rows/columns be linearly dependent without any addition subtraction? Am I missing something?

Comment: @flashburn Adding/subtracting rows preserves linear (in)dependence. In this case, you ended up showing that $r_1 - r_3 = 10 \, r_2\,$ (with $r_k$ standing for the $k^{th}$ row), which is a linear dependence between the three rows, which in turn means that the determinant is $0\,$..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A matrix is singular if two or more columns or rows have linear dependence. This means that you can write a column (or row) in terms of other columns (or rows) by multiplying any of them with a real number and adding to other columns (or rows). For this matrix

first row =  10* (second row) + third row.